# Documentation for undocumented symbols RandomMatrix and SharingList?

Tags: undocumented

In version 10.2, there are symbols `` Random`RandomMatrix `` and `` System`SharingList ``.

I tried some experiments of my own, but could not get anywhere. Does anyone have any information about these symbols, or know how they are supposed to be used?

Comment: The first does actually turn up when one types <code>?Random`*</code> but the other one doesn't turn up as an existing symbol, at least in version 10.1. What version are you using?

Comment: My version is 10.2,the complete format is System`SharingList

Comment: @Verbeia Can you give an example of the first function for how to use it?

Comment: RandomMatrix was already there in v9.  SharingList is just an option name for CloudObject, you can find it by searching the documentation, so I wouldn't call it undocumented.  Is there any particular reason you are interested in these specific symbols out of the many internal ones?  Mathematica, by nature, is transparent.  If you are looking for them, you'll always be able to take a peek at some internal components which are not meant for end-users.

Comment: If you need to generate a random matrix with good performance, use `RandomReal[1, {nrows,  ncols}]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm a Chinese user,and my version is "10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (August 30, 2015)",In our local version,the function of search is so bad,I cannon search it,even the MorphologicalTransform.How can push the bug to wolfram-research,Or you can help me?

Comment: You can always use the online documentation if you need access to the English documentation and your local Mathematica doesn't provide it: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObject.html  Ways to contact Wolfram support are here: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Comment: @Szabolcs All the way,thank you for your comment,^_^